# Adding Credits Testers via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits, facebook-test-users

I'm building an AIR application to manage Test Users a bit more efficiently. Part of this tool requires linking freshly made Test Users automatically to the Credit Tester of an application.

Is there any ways I can use something similar to https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users to add Test Users to the Credit Tester via Graph API using their IDs?

Thank you!